# Solr I/O increases over time

Tags: linux, solr, lucene, search-engine

I am running around eight `solr` servers (version `3.5`) instances behind a Load Balancer. All servers are identical and the LB is weighted by number connections. The servers have around 4M documents and receive a constant flow of queries. When the solr server starts, it works fine. But after some time running, it starts to take longer respond to queries, and the server I/O goes crazy to 100%. Look at the New Relic graphic:

[image]

If the servers behaves well in the beginning, I it starts to fail after some time? Then if I restart the server, it gets back to low I/O for same time and this repeats over and over.

Comment: Have you tried profiling? It would show some hotspots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is related to the content in [this blog post](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html).

What happens in this case is that queries are highly dependent of reading `solr` indexes. These indexes are in disk, to I/O i high. To optimize disk accesses, Linux OS creates a cache in memory for the most accessed disk areas. It uses free memory (not occupied my applications) for this cache. When the memory is full, the server needs to read from disks again. For this reason, when solr restarts, JVM occupies less memory and there is more free space for disk cache.

(The problem is happening in a server with 15Gb RAM and a 20Gb `solr` index)

The solution is to simple increase the server's RAM, so the whole index fits into memory and no I/O is required.

Comment: I don't understand this. The blog says MMapDirectory reads the Lucene index from the OS' disk cache. Why would this be counted against app memory? If it is seen as shared memory, why aren't the pages swapped back to disk as other disk IO needs cache? It's as though the memory used to read the file is taking memory away from cache, which would slow things down with time, but it the memory is cache, restarting shouldn't speed it up. If anything, restarting should hurt performance because the files have to be read from disk again.